# devstack error unable to find libvert client and libvert daemon

Tags: ubuntu, libvirt, devstack

i am installing devstack on ubuntu 14.04...i am facing an error while running ./stack.sh..i have installed libvert daemon though but y this error comes..this is the error..

```
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libvirt-clients
E: Unable to locate package libvirt-daemon-system
+functions-common:apt_get:1                exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  local r=100
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:489                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:489                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:492                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:498                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:384               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  [[ 100 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:501                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:50 generate-subunit        1492099156 202 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:503                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:506                      
/home/nandhini/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2017-04-13-160239.txt    
for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:512                  exit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Devstack is written to require Ubuntu Xenial or newer - your 14.04 version is no longer supported AFAICT.